# Hector Slam with Odometry

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, hector, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

I have already used Hector slam (without odometry data) to create a mapping process successfully. But now I want to use odometry data from my mobile Robot with hector slam node.

Is it possible? How can I achieve it? Can anyone share experience in writing an odometry node?

Thank you so much for helping me!

BTW, I am using fuerte 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118581/hector-slam-with-odometry/) by [Yuliang Sun](https://answers.ros.org/users/10781/yuliang-sun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use hector_mapping with a robot providing odometry (see "Use in place of gmapping" in the [setup tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot)). Odometry is not used within hector_mapping though, as in the original use case it was advantageous to be able to perform mapping without reliable odometry.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yuliang Sun](https://answers.ros.org/users/10781/yuliang-sun/) on 2014-01-19**:
I already created a map with hector_slam (without reliable odometry).   What I try to figure out is, if it is possible to use odometry data with hector_slam by writing an odometry node or something, which will gain the data from real odometry sensor.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-01-19**:
There will be no improvement in mapping performance by providing odometry data currently. It certainly would be possible to add support, but it hasn't been done so far.